# PHP Array not accessible

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Basically, i'm trying to get users data from a database using a class i found, it's parsing all data inside an array as shown here from the following function :

```
public function Get($field = NULL) {
        if ($field == NULL)
        {
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->last_query))
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($this->last_query);
            $data = $row[$field];
        }
        return $data;
}
```

Here's the PHP code i'm using to get the call this function

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if($_SESSION['csrfToken'] == $_POST['csrfToken']) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $Security->Salt($Security->secParam($_POST['password']));
        $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'");
        if($DB->num_rows() > 0) {
            $results = $DB->Get();
        } else {
            echo "Account not found";
        }
    }
}
```

If i do a var_dump on $results it shows the following

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(8) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(35) "email@email.com" ["email"]=> string(35) "email@email.com" 
        [2]=> string(32) "4f14dfef1efe0de64e2b176eac6051cd" ["password"]=> string(32) "4f14dfef1efe0de64e2b176eac6051cd" 
        [3]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
}
```

how can i access this data ? I've tried calling it by doing the following

```
$email = $results['email'];
echo $email;
```

But it's not displaying anything ?

Comment: Your script is probably vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there's only one result in this instance (I guess?) the array supports multiple.

So find the first result, then take the email from that:

```
echo $results[0]['email'];
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^
//   first result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tracking how arrays works. First you have array(1) and then into array another vars such as "email" or 1.

```
array(1) {  <---- THIS IS ARRAY OCCURED FOR FIRST "0" ARRAY.
```

What's about

```
             this
              \/
echo $results[0]["email"]; ?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_SESSION['csrfToken'] == $_POST['csrfToken']) {
    $password = $Security->Salt($Security->secParam($_POST['password']));
    $password = $DB->quoteStr($password);
    $email = $DB->quoteStr($_POST['email']);
    $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `email` = $email AND `password` = $password");
    return $DB->GetRow();
}

public function GetRow() {
    return mysql_fetch_array($this->last_query);
}
public function quoteStr($str) {
    return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($str)."'";
}
```

Comment: Answer with no explanatory prose at all. My face ---> :(

Comment: I already knew that, i just wanted it put inside an array for easier access although i must prop you for reminding me about securing my "Email" parameter ! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Marin Sagovac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1195557/marin-sagovac) question is the answer.

To break it down a little more, your var_dump output shows that $results is a nested array. The first part of the output:

```
array(1) { 
[0]=>
```

shows that $results consists of an array containing 1 element, at index 0, since that's where PHP starts indexing. This is the $results[0] part of Marin's response.

The element 0 of the $results array consists of an array with 8 elements.

```
[0]=>array(8) { 
[0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1"  
[1]=> string(35) "email@email.com" ["email"]=> string(35) "email@email.com"
```

Even though there are only 4 actual results, index 1-4, each one exists twice so that they can either be accessed by index or by its key. Arrays that can be accessed by a unique key, as opposed to an index, are known as associative arrays.

So, in this case, either will return the same value:

```
echo $results[0]["email"];
echo $results[0][1];
```

The [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function would also work, instead of var_dump.